# Carousel Issues

Tags: jquery, carousel

beulahprint.ie

I'm trying to add a simple carousel to my site. I'm a graphic designer, new to all this coding business. I have a carousel working for the #specialoffers div. But I want to get rid of the previous and next buttons, how do i do this?

Also, if I change the direction to horizontal, my carousel works, but images 2, 3 and 4 are invisible, why is this?

Finally, I would love to get my pagination numbers 1, 2, 3, 4 into little boxes with rollovers. How would I do this? I don't even know how they got there in the first place cos theyre not in my html body code. How would position them wherever I want within the special offers div?

Sorry for my ignorance, still learning :)

Cheers,
Colm

Answer (score 0):

to hide the next and previous buttons you could put this on the page after you have jquery and your carousel script loaded:

```
$(function() {
    $('.next').hide();
    $('.prev').hide();
})
```

of course this is assuming that the next and previous buttons have

```
class="next"
```

and

```
class="prev"
```

respectively on the appropriate HTML tag.